# Error while using regrex to extract years from a column in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, regression

I have a table with a column called "Filename" as seen in the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmAZ6.png).

I want to extract the years in those filename to another column called "Years" using regrex. Here is the code i used:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feTkk.png)
it created the "Years" column, but it has "NaN" all over instead of the years i want to extract [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imNBG.png)

Is there anything i can do to fix this?

I expected it to create a "Years" column with the years from "Filename" column in the same row

Comment: Please the code and input sample as text to the question, not as pictures. Also why is this question tagged `regression`? I think this tag should be deleted

Comment: @PhiPh, remove the boundaries or replace them with *underscore* : `statistics_df["Years"] = statistics_df["Filename"].str.extract("(\d{4})", expand=False)`